# Dimension of a hypersurface of $\mathbb C^n$ / of a cut by a hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

Defining the domain $$\Gamma[V]=\mathbb C [\bar x ]/I(V)$$ for any irreducible variety $V\subset \mathbb C^n$ (by *variety*, I mean only *zero set of a family of polynomials*), $\Gamma(V)$ for the field of fractions of $\Gamma[V]$ and $$\dim V=\operatorname{trdeg}_{\mathbb C}\Gamma (V),$$

> > **(1)** I am looking for different proofs that $$\dim V(P)\geqslant n-1$$

for a nonconstant irreducible polynomial $P\in \mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

> > **(2)** Why is it harder to show that $\dim V\cap V(P)\geqslant\dim V-1$ for any variety $V$?

**One proof of (1)?** Since $P$ is nonconstant, $P$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb C$, so there are $P_2,\dots,P_n$ such that $(P,P_2,\dots,P_n)$ is a transcendence basis of $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ (here we use the fact that the transcendence degree is well defined and in this case equal to $n$, which has a simple, elementary, combinatorial proof here) Now $(P)$ is radical since $P$ is irreducible, so $I(V(P))=(P)$ by the Nullstellensatz, so we are looking for $\operatorname{trdeg}_{\mathbb C} \mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(P)$ which is greater than or equal to $\operatorname{trdeg}_{\mathbb C}(P,P_2,\dots,P_n)/(P)=n-1$.

Comment: I changed $trdeg_{\mathbb C} \Gamma(V)$ to $\operatorname{trdeg}_{\mathbb C} \Gamma(V),$ coded as \operatorname{trdeg}_{\mathbb C} \Gamma(V). Note that this is NOT the same as if I had written \mathrm{trdeg}_{\mathbb C} \Gamma(V), in that context-dependent spacing happens. Thus: $$ \begin{align} & x\operatorname{trdeg} y & & \text{is coded as x\operatorname{trdeg} y, and} \\ \\ & x\operatorname{trdeg}(y) & &\text{is coded as x\operatorname{trdeg}(y),} \end{align} $$ whereas $$ \begin{align} & x\mathrm{trdeg} y & & \text{is coded as x\mathrm{trdeg} y.} \end{align}$$ You see that$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$the amount of space to the right of $\operatorname{trdeg}$ depends on whether there are parentheses to its right, whereas that doesn't happen with \mathrm{}. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks, looks better!